# Chromium OS Lime installation confusion

Tags: google-chrome-os

I Used to download Chromium Vanilla build Virtual-box image from hexxeh. recently i wanted to try Lime build which only gives a .img file.

I used the mentioned Windows Image Writer (link given on the lime website.) and a 8GB Transcend Website.

When i tried to boot from pen-drive, the screen only flashed and nothing happened.
Now when i tried to access my pendrive, it shows only 0.99 gb capacity.

What happened wrong. How can i recover my pendrive.

I tried to create vdi using `VBoxManage.exe convertdd chromiumos.img chromiumos.vdi` command given in [This link](http://www.chromiumosforge.com/2012/03/how-to-install-chromium-os-in.html). But it is not running on VBox either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reformatting the hard drive should restore your original capacity and render it bootable if done right - i favour the [HP formatting tool](http://www.bay-wolf.com/usbmemstick.htm) for the task.

Trying to install chromium after that should work as well. Lime supports more hardware than vanilla so its more likely its the USB drive than drivers

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote two posts that might help you. The first is: http://greenido.wordpress.com/2011/11/10/chromeos-in-virtualbox-test-drive-it/ In this post you can also find an image that will work for you (As I've checked it).

In case you wish to install it on your box try: http://greenido.wordpress.com/2012/01/09/install-chromiumos-on-your-old-laptop/
The most important aspect on the installation process is to check the computability of your computer. From what you describing it might be the reason for the black screen.